# UIAlertView after completion of NSLog

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone..

Actually i wanted to know is it possible to put an UIAlertView after the completion of NSLog as i wanted to check whether the statement really works or not as i cant check NSLog in the iphone.

Please suggest me whether it is possible and how?

Comment: what is mean by "Can't check NSLog in the iPhone ".

Comment: connect your iphone to system.. And using iphone configuration utility you can check the logs..

Answer (score 1):

**NSLog will still work on iPhone..
You can only see it in the console if you have attached the device to your mac..and then use the app.**

Anyways.

You can show your AlertView after log like this.( This Nslog is an example..replace with what is your actual log)

```
NSLog(@" Image Loaded");
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log" message:@"Image Loaded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
```

Comment: thanks subhank...this is fine ..actually i wanted to show this to client and the client is not technical so that he will be able to console in the xcode...

Answer (score 0):

If the NSLog statement works, it'll show up in the XCode console. So if you debug the app on your phone via XCode, you should see the NSLog. Or did you have something else on your mind ?

Comment: Let me explain it to you detailly...actually i am calling some images from server and showing it in tableview..it works fine for simulator but not in iphone..i think it is due to server problem..and wanted to show to the client by using this technique..please suggest me